# Best Practice to set the custom key for event handling in angular 6

Tags: angular

I have defined some custom keys in `json` file and i want to bind all those custom keys in `angular` for handling some functionality like in `angular` we can use `(blur)` events,similarly i want to use custom key for handling such events.

Example

myexample.ts file

```
    import {
      Component,
      OnInit
    } from '@angular/core';
    export class InputComponent implements OnInit {

    keys :any;
    constructor() {

      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.keys="keyup.control.z";
      }

      test()
      {
         console.log("test");
      }
   }
```

myexample.html

```
<input type="text" (keys)="test()" class="form-control">
```

Here i want to call the `test()` function on `keyup.control.z` event,so how to handle such type of custom key events in angular?

Thanks.

Comment: Are these custom keys used as constants?

Comment: please show a code example, what did you try?

Comment: No  @PareshLomate Sir custom keys will be in json file so it can be editable through json file also.

Comment: You want to call multiple function in `blur` event ?

Comment: You want to call multiple function in blur event in the basis of `custom keys`

Comment: @BhagwatTupe for click event you can call the function on click event, so similarly i want to call that some functions based on custom keys like ctrl+p,alt+p,etc.

Comment: @Sandy You can declare these key in your JSON and blur event you can check these key code on that basis you can handle it

Comment: @bhagwatTupe if i defined (keydown.alt.k) in html file then on that key i can call the function but here this (keydown.alt.k) key should be come from json file only, i can't define it in html file, i have to bind it through the json file only.

Comment: You want pass key event as a dynamically?

Comment: @bhagwatTupe Yes but how to bind that dynamic keys to events.